# mysqlslap phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

i have downloaded mysqlslap and i want to perform performance benchmark on a database which is in phpmyadmin, when i open the mysqlslap.exe, it just prints error connecting to mysqlslap database, no such database exists but it does not provide any option to select a particular database. can anyone help me with this please. i want to put the name of my database and perform performance benchmark with mysqlslap. Thanks in advance. i get the error below:

```
error when connecting to server 1049 unknown database mysqlslap
```

how do i change this database name?

Answer (score 2):

`mysqlslap` uses, by default,  a schema name of **mysqlslap**.

To fix your error you could either create it before run

```
CREATE SCHEMA `mysqlslap` ;
```

Or you can use

```
--create-schema=mysqlslap
```

As a parameter to mysqlslap to specify a different name.